# Разделение строки на равные части

Tags: php

Я сделал сделал разделение строки на равные части с хвостом:

```
function chunk($text, $parts) {
    $partSize = strlen($text)/$parts;
    $tailSize = strlen($text)%$parts;
    $arr = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $parts; $i++) {
        array_push($arr, substr($text, $i*$partSize, $partSize));
    }
    // Хвост
    if ($tailSize != 0) {
        $end = substr($text, $parts*$partSize + 1, $tailSize);
        array_push($arr, $end);
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Но всё же где-то в середине процесса начинают теряться символы. При использовании

```
json_encode(chunk('hellohellohello', 4))
```

Результат следующий:
[image: Результат]

Знаю, что скорее всего проблема здесь: $i*$partSize но не доходит =В

Comment: Вам нужно разбить именно на одинаковые части? или по количеству символов тоже подходит?

Comment: @AntonKucenko он уже разбил на части хвост отбрасывает если в нём не хватает символов для части. сейчас теряется символ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё же была моя ошибка: на месте *strlen($text)/$parts* получалось десятичное число, поэтому через пару циклов начинали пропадать буквы (я спутал с другим языком, где деление происходило нацело). Если вдруг у кого будет схожий вопрос, держите код (заранее извиняюсь, если плохо оптимизирован)

```
function chunked($text, $parts) {
    $partSize = floor(strlen($text)/$parts);
    $tailSize = strlen($text)%$parts;

    $arr = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $parts; $i++) {
        array_push($arr, substr($text, $i*$partSize, $partSize));
    }
    // Хвост
    if ($tailSize != 0) {
        $end = substr($text, $parts*$partSize, $tailSize);
        array_push($arr, $end);
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Так что ли?

```
$string = 'helloworld';
function array4me($string, $chunks)
{
    $array = str_split($string);
    $chunks = array_chunk($array, $chunks, false);
    $result = array();
    foreach ($chunks as $chunk)
    {
        $result[] = implode($chunk);
    }
    $result = implode(',', $result);
    return $result;
}

echo array4me($string, 4);
```

На выводе будет строка - hell,owor,ld

Comment: Я забыл упомянуть, что работаю с многобайтовыми строками, тем не менее о таком ходе я даже и не думал. Это решает часть моих проблем, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

И используйте функции mb_strlen() и mb_substr(); для работы с многобайтными строками `https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/book.mbstring.php`

Comment: Спасибо, снова выручаешь =В
Пока ошибок при работе со строками не было, но поставлю на всякий случай